# How to 'check' before picking off the Amqp/ RabbitMQ Queue (Spring AMQP)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, circuit-breaker

Scenario:
A microservice picks up a message from a RabbitMQ Queue, it's converted to an object and then the microservice makes a REST call to external service.

It's going to deal with thousands 'n thousands of these messages, is there a way of telling my consumer not to pick up a message off the Queue if we know the external Rest service is down?

I know I can do retries for an individual message once it's picked up, but I dont want to even pick it up if I know its down.
I dont want to deal with thousands of messages in DLQ.

Also it feels like a Circuit Breaker design pattern, but I cant find any specific examples of how to implement it with AMQP.

Extra info:
SpringBoot app, taking to RabbitMQ using spring amqp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, since you're starting event is the reception of a message, this seems highly unlikely. You could implement a health check to you Rest Service on a timer, and stop the listener on messages when service is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop and start the message listener container.

If you are using discrete containers you can stop/start the container bean.

If you are using `@RabbitListener`, provide an `id` attribute and wire in the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.

Then `registry.getMessageListenerContainer(myId).stop();`.

Comment: We were using discrete containers and this seems to work. thanks